# Why can't I see commited files in my shared repo?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I used TortoiseGit to create a bared repo, clone it, add some files in cloned directory, then commited all the files recursively.

When I browse clone, I can see the commited files. When I browse the origin repo, I can't see any files. Why ?

Comment: Is there some Git tutorial that does not cover this, i.e. does not explain `git push`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have committed the files are stored **locally** on your machine.
In order to **upload** them to the repo you have to push them.

Checkout this graphical display and follow the arrows.
[source - www.git-tower.com](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/command-line/remote-repositories/introduction)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a bit stupid but have you pushed your commits to your remote repository? Git is an decentralized version control system. You commit changes are first on your computer and can be pushed to a remote repository.

You can add your remote repository with

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then when the remote branch not exist you can push them with

```
git push origin master
```